# Diagrams not displaying in QGIS2web

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, mac, qgis2web, diagram

I am trying to create a web map using the QGIS2WEB plug-in from an existing map. I am new to QGIS and I don't know if this is possible?

When I try to export the map as a web map either in Openlayers3 or Leaflet format the diagram circles that I've used for the map disappear or don't display correctly (only the text labels are visible).

I've attached pictures of the problem and I'm using QGIS 2.8.4 Wien on a Mac if that is helpful. [image: What I would like the web map to look like][image: what it ends up looking like when I try to create a web map]

Comment: I don't think that the plugin has a solution for every qgis renderer, especially diagrams are not directly supported in openlayers without using some kind mapping server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid qgis2web does not support export of diagrams. It's also not something likely to be developed soon, unless someone decides specifically to take it on. Sorry not to have better news.

qgis2web *will* try to replicate your label settings, so if you can achieve something similar with labels, that could be an alternative.